# How to get the managed metadata column value in a list client object model

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, managed-metadata

I am trying to get values from a list for different columns like Title ,ID ,Region  Where Region is a metadata column .

I am able to get all the values except metadata column values . Pleas tell me how to get  it.

Below is my code

```
while (ListEnumerator.moveNext())
{
    var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();

    var ID = parseInt(currentItem.get_item('ID'));
    var ID = currentItem.get_item('ID');
    var Region = currentItem.get_item('Region');
    alert(Region);              
}
```

it is giving alert as object object.

Comment: For Managed Metadata, it matters which version of SharePoint  is used

Answer (score 7):

Assume the following Managed Metadata fields:

- `Tags` (`Multiple Taxonomy Field type`)
- `NewsCategory` (`Taxonomy Field type`)

### How to retrieve Managed Metadata field via CSOM in SharePoint 2013

[SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312495.aspx) value is represented as [SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312518.aspx):

```
//Get Taxonomy Field value
var newsCat = item.get_item('NewsCategory'); 
var newsCatLabel = newsCat.get_label();
var newsCatId = newsCat.get_termGuid();
```

**Multiple** [SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312495.aspx) value is represented as [SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312524.aspx) object

```
//Get Multiple Taxonomy Field value
var newsTags = item.get_item('Tags'); 
for(var i = 0; i < newsTags.get_count(); i++) {
    var newsTag = newsTags.getItemAtIndex(i);
    var newsTagLabel = newsTag.get_label();
    var newsTagId = newsTag.get_termGuid();

}
```

### How to retrieve Managed Metadata field via CSOM in SharePoint 2010

```
//Get Taxonomy Field value
var newsCat = item.get_item('NewsCategory'); 
var newsCatParts = newsCat.split('|');  //Format TermLabel|TermId
var newsCatLabel = newsCatParts[0];
var newsCatId = newsCatParts[1];


//Get Multiple Taxonomy Field value
var newsTags = item.get_item('Tags'); 
for(var idx in newsTags) {
      var newsTagsParts = newsTags[idx].split('|');
      var newsTagLabel = newsTagsParts[0];
      var newsTagId = newsTagsParts[1];

}
```

Comment: NOT WORKING I tried below this code as u said                                        


var Region = currentItem.get_item('Region');
var newsCatLabel = Region.get_label();
alert(newsCatLabel);

Comment: It seems that you are trying to get multiple Multiple Taxonomy Field value, the answer has been updated to reflect this case

Comment: Just would like to add that this method of getting the Taxonomy Values is only available in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: indeed, that's why the answer updated to address both versions, thanks mate.