# The other parameters for the CSR VIEW Template function

Tags: 2013, jslink, client-side-rendering

#### function myCSRtemplate( ctx )

All CSR examples out there only pass the ctx object to the template function:

```
FieldContext.Templates = {};
FieldContext.Templates.Fields = {
    "myColumn": {
        "View": myCSRtemplate
};
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(FieldContext);

function myCSRtemplate(ctx){
    var name = ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name;
    var value = ctx.CurrentItem[name];
    var ID = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
}
```

Is this a remnant of some early blogs because the Form overrides only receive one parameter?

#### function myCSRtemplate(ctx, CurrentFieldSchema, CurrentItem, ListSchema)

Is there another reason why we are all not using the default 2nd, 3rd and 4th parameter SharePoint passes into the function (for View templates)?

```
function myCSRtemplate(ctx, CurrentFieldSchema, CurrentItem, ListSchema){
    var name = CurrentFieldSchema.Name;
    var value = CurrentItem[name];
    var ID = CurrentItem.ID;
}
```

TIA

Danny

ICSR

Comment: Not sure what you are aming at, but are not those properties also available in the `ctx` object? Making it a "do what you like" thing? :)

Comment: I guess also must of the blogs around are quite easy proof-of-concept implementations not really using those variables

Comment: I wondered if there was an issue with those extra existing variables; even [the MSDN examples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a) do not use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answering my own question to get it out of the un-answered list*

Yes, the View Template functions get 4 parameters

Perfectly valid to use them