# Calculated Column display in filter of list

Tags: 2013, calculated-column-formula

Hi I'm using the this approach https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/118213/53772 to color an field of an list

e.g.

```
 =IF([Status]="red","<div style='color:red;'>red</div>","error")
```

which is coloring the text "red" in red. All good so far, but using the filter/sorting property of this column will display the `<div style='color:red;'>red</div>` insted of a red text. like this:
[image]

any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: Was the answer helpful? If so could you make it disappear from the SO unanswered list by marking it an answer. tnx

Comment: Hey did you get the answer? If yes, Please let me know because I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not

Note that the link you provide to mess with XSLT in Designer is not required; all you have to do is set the datatype of the Calculated Column to Number

HTML in Calculated Columns works since SP2010, but it is a hack not supported by Mirosoft

Your HTML will show up in plenty more places, see Pros & Cons at http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

Your only way out is Client Side Rendering (since SP2013), using JavaScript to only rewrite the output of the Field

See: [How does one alter the appearance of a managed metadata value in a list using JSLink?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149304/how-does-one-alter-the-appearance-of-a-managed-metadata-value-in-a-list-using-js)

And be sure to edit that CSR code with the WYSIWYG [Cisar Chrome Extension](https://365csi.nl/cisar)

Comment: @user2798895 agree with danny so you can do it by using some javascript hack.